# Mexico, Transit without Visa, does this count as double transit on stopover?

Tags: air-travel, transit, mexico

This is related to my last question:
[Confused about this stop over - Turkish airlines - Istanbul (IST) to Cancun (CUN)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162266/confused-about-this-stop-over-turkish-airlines-istanbul-ist-to-cancun-cun)

TK181 flight goes in a triangular pattern: Istanbul (IST) to Mexico City (MEX) to Cancun (CUN) to Istanbul (IST).

According to the emirates visa requirements tool, as a Sri Lankan national, I can transit through Mexico airside upto 24 hours without a VISA aslong as the onward flight is out of mexico. This doesn't allow double transit.

Since my destination is Sri Lanka to Bahamas and part of the route is above (from Cancun, I will go to Nassau Bahamas), can I transit through Mexico without a VISA given the stopover of TK181 in Mexico city?

Edit: It is possible that during the stopover (because it's 1 hour and 30 mins), we may not get off the plane (not sure).

Comment: You should make clear in this question that you possibly don't even get off the plane during the MEX stop.

Comment: The statement "This doesn't allow double transit" is far from precise. Your question might be more answerable if you attached as an image (after selecting "Edit" use the "Moon & Mountains" button above the composing space to attach a picture) of the actual text as it appears on whatever site generated it. You said "TIMTAC" in your other question...perhaps you meant "TIMATIC."

Answer (score 2):

[Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=lk&destination=bs&transit=mx) says:

> #### TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Passengers transiting through Mexico City (MEX) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

So TWOV is apparently only possible **if your only connection in Mexico happens in Mexico City airport (MEX), not in Cancun**.

In addition, **you need to stay airside**, so this means you cannot claim luggage and check it again (which you would need to do if you have hold luggage and you are "self-connecting" flights on different bookings/tickets) or even go to a check-in desk (which you would need to do if mobile/online check-in is not possible and you are self-connecting).

In any case, I don't see any direct flights from Cancun to Nassau (or from Mexico City, for that matter). What is your actual planned itinerary, and what are the airlines involved?